# Listar somente N arquivos utilizando o globule do nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

Estou utilizando o [globule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globule) para listar os arquivos do meu diretório.

O diretório em questão pode conter milhares de arquivos e por isso quero apenas trabalhar com uma quantidade limitada de arquivos.

No exemplo a seguir eu possui 15 arquivos e consegui trazer no array apenas os 10 que gostaria, porém o find continua buscando todos os arquivos e adicionando no array somente os que retornam true.

Gostaria que assim que chegasse na quantidade especificada a função já retornasse sem continuar a procura.

```
function escanearAte() {
   const ret = !(quantidade++ >= 10);
   console.log("item: " + quantidade + " | vai entrar no array: " + !(quantidade >= 10))
   return ret;
}

// procurar arquivos
const filesPath = globule.find(`**/*${extensionScan}`, {
        prefixBase: true,
        srcBase: directoryToScan,
        nodir: true,
        filter: escanearAte,
 });

 console.log(`Total de arquivos encontrados: ${filesPath.length}`);
```

Saída no console:

```
item: 1 | vai entrar no array: true
item: 2 | vai entrar no array: true
item: 3 | vai entrar no array: true
item: 4 | vai entrar no array: true
item: 5 | vai entrar no array: true
item: 6 | vai entrar no array: true
item: 7 | vai entrar no array: true
item: 8 | vai entrar no array: true
item: 9 | vai entrar no array: true
item: 10 | vai entrar no array: false
item: 11 | vai entrar no array: false
item: 12 | vai entrar no array: false
item: 13 | vai entrar no array: false
item: 14 | vai entrar no array: false
item: 15 | vai entrar no array: false
Total de arquivos encontrados: 10
```

Comment: Não dá para quebrar, essa lib que está usando é uma fachada implementada em cima da lib [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) que esconde os métodos `pause`, `resume` e `abort`. Veja o código fonte do módulo [globule](https://github.com/cowboy/node-globule/blob/master/lib/globule.js). Sugiro, não significa que tenha que seguir, que reescreva o código usando a lib [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado irei reescrever.